# Replace object's normals with normal map

Tags: cycles-render-engine, blender-internal-render-engine, normal-map

I baked the normal map in substance painter and it looks fine in substance painter, but when I exported the textures to blender cycles the normal map does not seem to be applied to the model in the same way as substance painter - substance painter seems to ignore the normals of the low poly model, but blender does not.

Is there a way to achieve the same look of the normal map as in substance painter?

model in Substance Painter
[image]

model in blender cycles
[image]

model in blender view port
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this can be eliminated in two ways the simplest and immediate is to set, the angle of **smooth to 30 degrees**,
[image]

or second way is to determine which edges should be planar, but this requires a selection of all edges of planar faces by setting the **sharp edges**, and adding a layer of **custom normal edge.**
[image: Smoothing Edge Split Modifier]

However, I suggest you also take a look at the manual, where you can better understand these commands.
https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/meshes/editing/smoothing.html